# Cannot find either column "ssma_oracle" or the user-defined function or aggregate "ssma_oracle.to_char_date", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server

We are migrating our database from Oracle to MS SQL server (For some business reasons, though we loved oracle). So we are using SSMA (SQL server Migration Assistant) as such the tool when migrating our database will create a Schema and auto generate some functions under "[ssma_oracle]"
to support some oracle functions like to_char, to_date . So on migrated dtabase a new schema is created with functions eg:
**[ssma_oracle].[to_char_numeric]
[ssma_oracle].[to_number2]** etc

However there is one method that the tool is failing to create **"ssma_oracle.to_char_date"** as such when I run my java app which was earlier pointing to oracle and now pointed to MS SQL server ( Of course I made changes on java side for native SQL queries, changing dialect etc) and when I run a update on a hibernate java object I am getting ***"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] Cannot find either
column "ssma_oracle" or the user-defined function or aggregate "ssma_oracle.to_char_date", or the name is ambiguous."***

So when I browse the new database on MS sql server I see that this method is not created.
Is that a bug in the tool ?
More info on SSMA tool and what functions it creates is at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/project-settings-conversion-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver16
We are using : Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)

Answer (score 0):

The ssma_oracle.to_char_date function is an advanced feature that uses the **"SSMA4OracleSQLServerCollections.NET"** assembly, so one can NOT just script it out like a traditional database object.

In SQL2019, there is an advanced security option called ***‘clr strict security’*** and by default it is enabled.  This feature does NOT allow assemblies to be created in a system database.

After I disabled the security option at the database instance level, in the schema I was migrating form Oracle in SSMA tool, I was able to successfully migrate/create the assembly that is used by the to_char_date function.